# How can I find the latest stable kernel for Ubuntu?

Tags: kernel

I have gone through many posts, and many threads of the last 30 minutes reading about Linux kernels. The problem I am having is I upgraded to the latest mainline kernel back when it fixed the processor exploits.

The **kernel was unstable**, and I had a lot of problems with programs. Now I would like to move to the latest **STABLE** kernel. There are many duplicate threads, but from my understanding the **mainline kernels are not stable** - but they are the latest. I would like to locate the **latest stable kernel** besides the LTS kernels.

**Does apt-cache display the latest stable kernel?**

When I run the command apt-cache linux-image I am presented with all of these:

[View the list here](https://pastebin.com/BRvYXwQj)

I could not post the list due to the limit of characters

I have chosen to install linux-image-4.15.0-041500rc7-generic - Linux kernel image for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP for now since it is listed, but I am unsure if this is even a stable kernel under their stable line?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by 'stable.' That term could mean several things, and our definition may differ from yours.

Comment: software that runs consistently without crashing aka stable

Comment: Anything with `rc` is **NOT** stable rather  it is a release candidate. The most recent stable version is `14.14.15`. See the instructions at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade

Comment: you probably mean `apt-cache search linux-image`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For your release of Ubuntu,

1. Ensure you have the -update and -security repositories enabled.
2. `sudo apt update` (or `sudo apt-get update`)
3. Install the `linux-image-generic` metapackage to install the latest kernel that is packaged and tested for your release of Ubuntu. The metapackage will pull in several dependencies including the actual kernel packages themselves.

   Using the metapackage will ensure you get upgrades as they become available.

Note that apt cannot remove kernels from other sources - you must clean up those yourself.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Ubuntu Kernel Release Schedule]
<sup>**Ubuntu Kernel Release Schedule**</sup>

[image: Ubuntu Kernel Support Schedule]
<sup>**Ubuntu Kernel Support Schedule**</sup>

ref [Ubuntu Kernel Support and Schedules](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Support)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/917278)

Comment: fixed this ,post screenshots.